# Why is my React fetch weather API so buggy/temperamental?

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm trying to fetch weather API after setting input onChange and button onClick. It kept returning undefined when I tried to .then (data => {setWeather(data)})
So I applied a solution from a youtube tutorial that uses a conditional operator to display component that goes as below in my App.

This basically worked, but it's so buggy and sensitive that even if I just add a className for some css in WeatherDisplay.jsx it crashes and starts returning undefined, much less any of the other things I need to do to it to get it looking right.

Would be grateful if anyone could tell me why, or even better provide a better alternative?
**Edit: It now just no longer works at all and continues to return undefined even when I've reverted it to the code that was working**

```
function handleClick(query) {
  fetch(
    `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&units=${unit}&appid=${apiKey}`,
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setWeather(data);
      console.log(data);
    });
  setWeatherReturn({
    type: weather.weather[0].description,
    temp: weather.main.temp,
    image: weather.weather[0].icon,
  });
}
```

---

```
{
  typeof weather.main != "undefined" ? (
    <WeatherDisplay
      weatherType={weatherReturn.type}
      weatherTemp={weatherReturn.temp + "°C"}
      weatherImg={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${weatherReturn.image}@2x.png`}
    />
  ) : (
    ""
  );
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show more of your component (it's very hard to help with the snippets you've pasted), but it looks like you're trying to use `setWeatherReturn` outside of your `then` async chain.

Comment: Please share the error you are running into when your app crashes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `setWeatherReturn` to process the weather data outside the then chain, so it's likely never loaded at that point.

The simple fix is just moving the `setWeatherReturn` within that callback:

```
function handleClick(query) {
  fetch(
    `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&units=${unit}&appid=${apiKey}`,
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setWeather(data);
      setWeatherReturn({
        type: data.weather[0].description,
        temp: data.main.temp,
        image: data.weather[0].icon,
      });
    });
}
```

Either way, you shouldn't use state for data derived from state (your `weatherReturn`), since it's then very easy to have that derived data be out of sync with the state it's derived from (e.g. you call `setWeather` and forget to call `setWeatherReturn`); instead use `useMemo`.

With that in mind, a simple stand-alone component that loads weather information and formats it might look like this.

The idea is that `useEffect` is automatically triggered when the query or unit changes, and the `useMemo` similarly when the raw data gets loaded.

If the data isn't yet loaded, the `useMemo` callback will return undefined, so the component itself just says "loading".

```
const apiKey = '...';
function WeatherLoader({ query, unit }) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&units=${unit}&appid=${apiKey}`,
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(setData);
  }, [query, unit]);
  const formattedWeatherData = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) return undefined;
    return {
      type: weather.weather[0].description,
      temp: weather.main.temp,
      image: weather.weather[0].icon,
    };
  }, [data]);
  if (!formattedWeatherData) return <>Loading...</>;
  const { type, temp, image } = formattedWeatherData;
  return (
    <WeatherDisplay
      weatherType={type}
      weatherTemp={`${weatherReturn.temp}°C`}
      weatherImg={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${image}@2x.png`}
    />
  );
}
```

You would use this e.g.

```
<WeatherLoader query="New York" unit="C" />
```

(or whatever `unit` takes as a value).

Comment: Thank you.
This made me realise I've got some glaring holes in my knowledge of react and I was trying to implement things I didn't conceptually understand, so I'm going to bookmark this and go away and do some learning, and hopefully come back to implement this correctly in a couple of weeks.
Thanks for taking the time, I appreciate it.